# Haskell - Basic Tail Recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, tail-recursion

I have a function that has parameters

```
whatIndex ::  (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Integer
```

where I return the index of a inside [a], starting at 0, or return -1 if it's not found. This is what I wrote

```
module WhatIndex where

whatIndex ::  (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Integer

whatIndex p [] = -1

whatIndex p (a:as) 
    | p==a = index
    | otherwise = whatIndex p as
    where index = 1+whatIndex p as
```

Obviously, I'm not correctly increasing index here. Any idea why this isn't working? Also, I cannot change parameters.

========================

Here is some basic input/output

```
whatIndex 3 [] = -1
whatIndex 2 [1,2,3,2,1]=1
whatIndex 1 [1,2,3,2,1]=0
whatIndex 'b' ['a' .. 'z']=1
```

Comment: What should this be doing? Could you provide a test case or 2?

Comment: its a standard .index() function on an array I believe. I believe he's expecting this to return the index of the element within the list e.g.:

whatIndex 17 [1,2,3,4,5,15,16,17,19] = 7

Comment: Yes, basically I am making an index function. I can't seem to get the logic figured out as to how to increment index.

Comment: BTW, what you really want here is a function that returns `Maybe Int`, because you want to make it clear in the type that the function is partial. Such a function, `elemIndex`, already exists in `Data.List`--you can take a look at the source [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#elemIndex).

Answer (score 5):

`1+whatIndex p as` will go through all of the remaining list and count them, it won't give you the index. Just use an iterative recursive helper function like this...

You can use either a local function, or the lifted version, which is what I have here.

```
whatIndex' ::  (Eq a) => Integer -> a -> [a] -> Integer

whatIndex' _ _ [] = -1

whatIndex' i p (x:xs) 
    | p == x = i
    | otherwise = whatIndex' (i+1) p xs

whatIndex p xs = whatIndex' 0 p xs

main = print $ whatIndex 'a' "bbbbaccc"
```

Here's a non tail-recursive version:

```
whatIndex p (x:xs)
    | p == x = 0
    | otherwise = 1 + whatIndex p xs
```

Tail recursion refers to a class of recursive functions where the "last" or "final" function call in a recursive function is to the function itself. So that means that the function is not calling some other function (like `+`) in the "tail position" (the last place where a function call takes place). You can clearly see that the final function that is called in the first version of `whatIndex` is `whatIndex` whereas the final function that is called in the second version (with a call to `whatIndex` as a parameter) is `+`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call

Edit: here's a version that corresponds more closely with your specification, although it's a bit convoluted and inefficient.

```
whatIndex p xs 
    | not (any (==p) xs) = -1
    | otherwise = whatIndex' p xs where
        whatIndex' p (x:xs)
            | p == x = 0
            | otherwise = 1 + whatIndex' p xs
```

Comment: I cannot change the parameters.

Comment: This isn't changing any parameters of `whatIndex`, it's the exact same as Pubby's answer, except the local function has been lifted to the top level scope.

Comment: Also your question said "tail recursion" which implies some kind of accumulator parameter. If you wanted a non tail-recursive version you should've specified that.

Comment: No I definitely want a tail recursion answer. I'm a noobie at tail recursion so I may not be completely understanding of what's going on in this code. 

However, you have 

    whatIndex' ::  (Eq a) => Integer -> a -> [a] -> Integer

where my restrictions don't have an Integer.

Comment: No, you want a non tail-recursive one. I'll add that though.

Comment: I may be getting confused on what exactly tail recursion is, but I am supposed to make it tail-recursive, so that is what I want. Sorry if I'm being confusing.

Comment: okay sorry, you are right. I'm not looking for tail recursive, apparently, even though the instructions say to implement it using tail recursion. The new format you posted is the one that I am familiar with. However, your version doesn't work, though I understand it. It works for almost all cases, but it failed on this (eqTest (whatIndex True [False,False,False]) "==" (-1))

The output was 2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24409/discussion-between-soulzityr-and-wes)

Answer (score 3):

Try using an accumulator parameter if you want tail recursion:

```
whatIndex :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Integer
whatIndex =
  let whatIndex' count p [] = -1
      whatIndex' count p (a:as)
        | p==a = count
        | otherwise = whatIndex' (count + 1) p as
  in whatIndex' 0
```

Comment: Your method has more parameters than allowed. I don't have Integer -> a -> [a], just a -> [a]

Comment: @Soulzityr No it doesn't. That's only for the local function.

Comment: I'm using the Eclipse plug-in, writing a module so I won't and shouldn't be using let or in keywords. Does that change how to do this?

Comment: @Soulzityr I don't understand those requirements,  but use Wes's answer then. It is doing the same thing, but the `whatIndex'` function is at global scope instead of local.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. My requirements are convoluted. I need to sort out why what I thought was tail recursion, in fact, isn't. My knowledge was based on popular online tutorials too...